# How can I register Mouse Events in the Scene window of the Editor?

Tags: map-editor, unity

I want to create a custom level editor for the level designers that should allow them to place predefined objects in Unity3d similar to the Terrain wizard.

How can I register Mouse Events in the Scene window of the Editor?

Comment: This does of course not answer your question, but in my current project I integrated the map editor into the game itself. So in order to edit a map, the mapper plays it in the game and then clicks on a "Map Editor" button which will be hidden in the release build.

Comment: That's a nice concept. However I can't give up the full feature set of the Unity Editor and I sure as hell ain't gonna reimplement all of it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is something you are looking for. This allows you to register mouse events in the scene, when a game object with the specified type is selected in the hierarchy.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor(typeof(SomeScriptType))]
public class MyEditorPlayer : Editor 
{
    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        int controlID = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);

        switch (Event.current.GetTypeForControl(controlID))
        {
            case EventType.mouseDown:
                GUIUtility.hotControl = controlID;
                Debug.Log("MouseDown");
                Event.current.Use();
                break;

            case EventType.MouseUp:
                GUIUtility.hotControl = 0;
                Event.current.Use();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute to your class to run events in edit mode:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class myclass: MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update() 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but I want to only process Mouse Events in the LevelEditor window.

Comment: How i tell you can do it with ExecuteInEditMode, add only your mouse event/s in the class and you got.

Comment: I can see what your trying to say, but it is clear that others do not. Perhaps you should expand upon your answer?